# Getting location data in weather api

Tags: windows-phone-7, weather-api

I am working with weather apps for windows phone 8 and wondering how to get all country data that supported by weather api?

Is it just like getting all location supported name and display it into my `longlistselector` in my apps?

I came across 2 promising apps: forecast and OpenWeatherMap but can't find anything about getting location data from these services.

Comment: So whats the question?  You should probably Rework your question.  Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: i'm sorry English is not my native language, my question is what weather api that provide their supported country data.. so I can give user selection of country that supported by this weather api